# how to make a portrait image responsive and keep ratio?

Tags: css, image, responsive

I have a **portrait** picture (original size width :2500px height : 4500px) and I want to place this image in a modal div . the modal has width: 100vw and height: 100vh .this is the structure:

```
<div class="modal">
   <div class="image-wrapper>
      <img src="..." />
   </div>
</div>
```

my question is how can I make this **portrait** image responsive in all width and height and also keep the aspect **ratio**. what should be the CSS like ?   what should be the width and the height of image-wrapper and also the img (image) ?

Comment: Investigate object-fit: contain.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.modal {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.modal--horizont {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

.image-wrapper {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
   <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/450/250" />
   </div>
</div>

<div class="modal modal--horizont">
   <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/450/250" />
   </div>
</div>
```